# Select last insert id

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting a record and i want to use the id of the last record inserted.
This is what i have tried:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO customer
                (first_name, last_name, email, password, 
                date_created, dob, gender,  customer_type)
        VALUES(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, 
                :date_created, :dob, :gender, :customer_type)' 
        . ' SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()' ;
```

I am getting the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()'.

Can anyone show me where is my mistake?
Thanks!

Comment: Note: I'm setting this as a reference of a duplicated question. However, you're adviced to use PDO or MySQLi instead of plain old mysl_*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id)

```
mysql_query($sql);
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

When that function is run after you've executed your INSERT statement in a mysql_query() command its result will be the ID of the row that was just created.

Comment: Actually im having a problem now, 
mysql_insert_id() [function.mysql-insert-id]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost'

Answer (score -1):

You can do another query:

`$last_id = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";`

Or try to add `;` in your query:

`INSERT INTO customer
(first_name,
last_name,
email,
password,
date_created,
dob,
gender,
customer_type)
VALUES(:first_name,
:last_name,
:email, 
:password, 
:date_created, 
:dob, 
:gender, 
:customer_type)<b>;</b>' . ' SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()';`