# How to retrieve the latest row from table in php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, row

I try to retrieve the latest added bookingID from table booking but I do not know how to get it.
The scenario: when user click 'submit' button, mysql query will generate a parentBookID and store userID, eventID in table booking.Then query will get the created parentBookID to insert into table bookingDetail, user will make multiple bookings and these detail will store in table bookingDetail with same parentBookID.

The problem is, I do not know to get the current parentBookID to be store in table bookingDetail from table booking.

```
<?php

session_start();


if ( !isset($_SESSION['AUTHORIZED_USERNAME']) || empty($_SESSION['AUTHORIZED_USERNAME']) )  {
header("location:index.php");
}else{
$user=$_SESSION['AUTHORIZED_USERNAME'];
$userID= $_SESSION['AUTHORIZED_CUSTNO'];
$event=$_SESSION['EVENT_ID'];
 include('db.php');

 //check submitted totalDay
 if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['totalDay'])) {


//insert parentBookingID
$parent=mysql_query("INSERT into booking (custNo, eventID,dateBook) VALUES ('$userID','$event',NOW())");

//no logic
$queryParent="SELECT parentBookID from booking where custNo='$userID' and eventID='$event'";
$queryParentResult=mysql_query($queryParent);
while($parentBook = mysql_fetch_array($queryParentResult)){
    $parentBookID=$parentBook['parentBookID'];

$totalDay=$_POST['totalDay'];
$allBooth="";


foreach ($totalDay as $d) {

    echo $d;

    $bookingInfo  = $d;
    $bookingInfo = explode(" ", $bookingInfo);
    echo $bookingInfo[0]; // boothAlias
    echo $bookingInfo[1]; // boothID
    echo $bookingInfo[2]; // day



    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bookingDetail WHERE boothID='$bookingInfo[1]' and day='$bookingInfo[2]' and username='$user'");

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if ($num_rows) {
            echo "Exist";
        }else{

    $str = "INSERT INTO bookingDetail (username, custNo, eventID, date, day, boothAlias, boothID, parentBookID) VALUES ('$user', '$userID','$event',NOW(),'$bookingInfo[2]','$bookingInfo[0]','$bookingInfo[1]','$parentBookID');";
    $res = mysql_query($str);

    if($res)
            echo 'Success';
    else
            echo 'Failure';

    $allBooth= substr($allBooth, 0, -2); 

echo "<p>Booth(s): <strong>$allBooth</strong>&nbsp;<strong>$user</strong>&nbsp;<strong>$event</strong><strong>$userID</strong></p>\r\n";

    }
}
    }

    header("refresh:5;url=mybooking.php");
echo "<img src='loading16.gif' style='margin-top:8px; float:left'/>";
echo 'You\'ll be redirected in about 5 secs. If not, click <a href="mybooking.php">here</a>.';  

}else{

echo "You do not make any booking";
    header("refresh:5;url=booking2.php");
    echo "<img src='loading16.gif' style='margin-top:8px; float:left'/>";
    echo 'You\'ll be redirected in about 5 secs. If not, click <a href="booking2.php">here</a>.';   
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to call `mysql_insert_id()`.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+mysql_insert_id

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select last insert id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266604/select-last-insert-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column in `booking`, you could use `mysql_insert_id();` to get it.

Comment: how to apply this mysql_insert_id()? i got read some sample but i do not how to apply it in my coding

Comment: You would use it after you insert the row on `booking` to get the id, like `$parentBookID = mysql_insert_id();`

Answer (score 0):

you may set a column like id or timestamp, so you can use max() or order by id desc (SQL language) to get what you want